# OAuth 2.0 Playground Error 403: access_denied

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth, nodemailer

I am getting an Authorization Error from OAuth 2.0 Playground when trying to Authorize APIs. I have checked the permissions on the app multiple times (as I am the OWNER), I have fixed security issues(google asking questions), tried multiple browsers and multiple email accounts(under new projects). Below is the error message:

```
Error 403: access_denied
The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer (recipe.tracker.app@gmail.com).
Learn more
Request Details
access_type=offline
response_type=code
redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
prompt=consent
client_id=765247627523-mhvqb7sc2or6rittk8dp0ti7b1ba8eel.apps.googleusercontent.com
scope=https://mail.google.com
```

Comment: The Gmail API is not part of your project (scope=https://mail.google.com). Which APIs are you trying to access?

Comment: not sure. I am trying to bypass the errors that arise when gmail doesnt allow nodemailer to send emails to/from a gmail account. There are videos and instructionals online that advice to use XOAuth 2 inorder to make the connection secure and to go through easier. And I keep getting stuck at the OAuth 2.0 Playground part....i think it should work since the setup worked the other day.I just couldnt get the app to work so I decided to get knew client id and client secret today with no luck.

Comment: Your question lacks real details. If your goal is to send emails via Gmail, use `Less Secure Apps`. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daniyal dehleh's original answer that solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756266/error-403-access-denied-the-developer-hasn-t-given-you-access-to-this-app-despi)

Solution to my OAuth 2.0 Playground error:

1. Go to your developer console.
2. Go to OAuth consent screen.
3. Go to +Add users, under test users.
4. Add the users for the test (even the owner email address if not working without it)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Solution for me was to

1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Enable less secure apps
2. https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha Enable this functionality
3. add the Email to Test users while app is in development mode
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHB93.png)